# Append list item to a for loop list in Jinja with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small issue with trying to append a list item to a for loop after an Ajax call. The list item get's appended to the top of the list but I want it to be appended at the bottom of the list. Thanks for you help.

Here is a snippet:

HTML:

```
{% for this in that %}
<ul class="list-stream" id="reply_sent">
{% if this == cool %}
<li class="cool">
......html code...
</li>
{% else %}
<li class="not-cool">
......html code...
</li>
{% endif %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...jquery / ajax code.....
success: function (response) {
$("#reply_sent").append(response);
},
```

The html returned in response is:

```
<li class="cool">
 ....html code ....
</li>
```

I want this to be added to the bottom of the list but it gets added to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Here are the changes I made to make it work.

For the HTML:

```
<ul class="list-stream" id="{{ some unique value you get from each    outer for loop }}">
```

{% for this in that %}

.....code ....

{% endfor %}

For the JavaScript:

```
success: function (response) {
$(".list-stream").append(response);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the problem is with the alignment of the list items, try this css

```
#reply_sent li{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, unfortunately that did not help

Comment: hit `F12` and check the DOM to see if the `<li>` actually gets appended to the top of `<ul>`

Comment: Yes it gets added there, however it doesn't show up in the <ul>. The <li> shows after the request to the server is completed

Comment: Aha! so the problem is with the styling! Can you update the question with all the css properties of the `ul` and the `li`s? You can see those in the Developer Panel (`F12`)

Comment: the issue was not the style, I figured it out. I will add my solution.